# How to setup powerpoint's custom functions across many powerpoint files

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

Because some personal functions are often used, I have developed macros and they work quite well. But, now I have a problem.

I have created custom functions (macro) in a new ribbon tab, and it saves much time to process the powerpoint.

The setting of the ribbon goes with the program. Thus, no matter what files to open, the custom tabs are there and remain the same.

But, the problem is the custom functions go with the file, not the powerpoint program, I can't execute the function for other files.

It will be ok, if the ribbon goes with the file or the marco can be as a global setting.

I have tried best to find the way, but for now, I can do is to create as many tabs as files to open. So there are many the same custom macro buttons on the ribbon. It's really stupid and ease to make confused. Is there some smarter way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: You have following problems,, **1. You have created Ribbon TAB & want to appear only with particular file. 2. The custom function is not working with other PPT files.** Please confirm if I'm correctly interpreted the Question !

Comment: @RajeshS Yes, you are correct. 1. I want to custom Ribbon Tab for particular file. 2. It is not possible to develop global macro functions. But, is there other technique able to use?

Comment: If you create an add-in from your file with the macros, then load the add-in (File | Options | Add-ins | Manage: PowerPoint Add-ins and add your add-in), the ribbon modifications will be there and your macros will be available no matter what presentation file is open.

Comment: @RayKao, Yes the Macro can be global,, means you can use particular Macro in all open PPt files. Go to DEVELOPER Tab, Click Macro, you find dialogue **Find Macro In**, has two options 1. Current ppt 2, ALL Open PPTs. Select 2nd one.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I don't know powerpoint can create add-in with the macro and will try to explore more. It's an important information. Thank you.

Comment: @RajeshS Yes, I know your idea now. The simplest way is to open a dumb pptm for the marco to be a global function. Yes it will work, but I will try to learn add-in. Add-ins seems to be more like a program-level setting as same as the Ribbon.

Comment: If you are  familiar with XML then it can help you to enable & disable Commands & Ribbons.